# Get a developer certificate for iOS

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I've an apple developer account, but I can't add my Mac to the account. I found a useful guide [here](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/28/getting-an-apple-developer-certificate/), so I created the certificate of my Mac, now I've to submit it to the iOS developer portal, but when I try to add another Mac as developer it shows this screen:

[image]

You can see that in my pic I can't add a developer certificate, why? I'm not understanding why I can't add my Mac to this developer account. I hope you can help me to fix this issue. The account has only 2 Macs with you can develop, I guess it's not because there are too much developers Mac.

**UPDATE**

Here you can see what I've on the main page in iOS dev center:

[image]

Comment: Is this a company developer account or an individual developer account? Individual developer accounts are for one user and therefore only one Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once certificate is **enough** !!!

Actually you can export certificate from your Keychain Access from the Mac you have added. It will be exported as certificate.p12 and you can give a password whatever you want. See [this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3vAi.png), you need to right click on a single certificate.

Just transfer that exported certificate to other Mac and double click on it. It will ask password so enter which you gave when exported.

Now you can use provisioning profiles at both location i.e. on both Mac.

Image taken from [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867878/missing-private-key-in-the-distribution-certificate-on-keychain/12867963#12867963)

Comment: Ok, if I've not the access to the Mac who generate this certificate? There's a way? I tried to download the certificate from the iOS dev center, then I clicked on it and it opened keychain, but I'm not sure if I've installed the certificate on my Mac

Comment: @lucgian841 you have to ask that person to follow the process I mentioned, or you need to revoke the certificate and create a new certificate. but again you need to do process in order to allow his mac to work.

Comment: so I've to do this stuff: 1. Ask to the person who generated first the certificate 2. Obtain the .p12 file install on my Mac 3. Get the provisioning profile from iOS dev center

Comment: What happened if I revoke one of these two certificate and I generate a new certificate for my Mac? Because it's a bit hard to know where's the Mac who generate this certificate. I update my question with a pic the person who own the certificates is the same.

Comment: @lucgian841 If you revoke, earlier certificate will not work. You have to export from your keychain and send to them in order to get provisioning profile working on their mac.