# No identities from profile "..." (happened after I upgraded to xcode 5)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I hit this weird problem that a profile used to work and does not expire now keeps telling me that "No identities from profile ..." and xcode prompted me that it can fix the issue by downloading a new profile. But that did NOT fix the issue and actually I found xcode did not download profile either. 
[image: no valid sign identity]

I tried to download a certificate from that profile from developer.apple.com and re-installed it. But xcode still complained "no identities".

I let xcode refresh profile from account tab, did not work either.  I even deleted that profile from developer.apple.com and let xcode refresh profile, still no avail.

I checked keychain and verified that the certificate was in "My certificates" (I did not doubt that actually b/c it used to work so it should be there, right?)

So basically I run out of thought, any suggestions ?

BTW, I remembered this happened when I upgraded to xcode 5 and add a new device for development (Not necessarily the reason of course)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867878/missing-private-key-in-the-distribution-certificate-on-keychain

Above answer may also help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

i tried everything!! this was the only thing that worked for me: Simply create a new production certificate AND create a new provisioning profile with the same bundle ID. (Yes, this will work if you are updating an app that is already live). Download the cert and prov. profile and run both (double click). Now repeat step 6 and archive. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please check in keychain that is there a key prepared for the certificate which you are using for the application.

Comment: Yes I checked keychain and there was a certificate for that profile and I do not think your comments about "profile linked with this certificate only." is correct. I have profile contained more than more certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go in Xcode --> Preferences --> Select your App ID from the left window --> Click on "View details" --> Finally click on the arrow to update your certificates.

After the procedure, go in Build Settings and select your provisioning profile. Now, you can see your identities.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even though I had the right certificate, keys, and provisioning profile installed.
The problem was that I hadn't added the account in XCode. I had never done it, but it seems now it's mandatory.

So in XCode Preferences, Accounts tab, if your Apple ID is not present, make sure you add it.
For me, it resolved the problem immediately.