# Provisioning profile doesn't include any certificate for which the matching private key is installed in the keychain

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have the problem while attaching distribution certificates to Enterprise app. Xcode throwing an error

> Provisioning profile doesn't include any certificate for which the matching private key is installed in the keychain (Xcode 8).

I have searched a lot but didn't find satisfactory answer for Xcode 8 (latest answer).

I have following queries on solutions I found in the internet:

1. Use Automatically manage signing: is it not going to create any issue for other apps using the same distribution certificate?
2. Export private key from older machine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867963/2741603 posted long ago, still is this going to work ? or do we have any other new alternatives?

Comment: Your certificate is not based on your private key. You can either create a new certificate in Apples developer center or, if someone else created the certificate, get the private key of the creator and add it to your Key Chain.

Answer (score 2):

Your Keychain is missing the certificate i.e. p12 file for the selected provisioning profile. You have to just open the .p12 file , if you have already else create a new one from your apple developer account.
Then **Clean** and **Build** your Xcode Project.

I will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

1. Create a new production certificate from the machine you need to deploy from.
2. Create a new ad-hoc provisioning profile and make sure that the newly added certificate is included in it
3. Download both files to your machine and double click them
4. Choose the new provisioning profile in Xcode code-signing settings

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I was missing the installation of APNS's .p12 certificate on my mac. After installation of .p12 certificate problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue. My UDID is in the provisioning profile. I've downloaded the development provisioning profile and still get:

> Provisioning profile "ProfileName" doesn't include any certificate for which the matching private key is installed in the keychain.

Not sure what to do to rectify