# IOS App archive and uploading

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, archive, provisioning-profile

When I tried to archive the app I just created, I received this error. Is there any guru who can help me explain this issue and give me instruction step by step how to fix this problem. Appreciate it.

[image: here is the image for the problem]

But there really is one in my keychain

[image: Certificate in my keychain]

Comment: Try re-generating your provisioning profile using your distribution certificate, the error says it currently doesn't. If you don't use any tools you can do this in the developer portal at developer.apple.com

Comment: Please check your build settings and make sure all the Debug / Release schemes are selected with this profile. I suspect that the one you selected in General tab is fine, however, the ones in the Build Settings and Code Sign entity section are still having the old ones, try going to each item and select the right certificate and team ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure your Profile is same as you selected in General Tab drop down. Also, you are confident that you are having the p12 for the profile. Do the following.

Go to the Build Settings tab and navigate to codesign. In that section, there is CodeSign, Provisioning profile and profile(deprecated), team selection. Please select those manually so they don't have "Multiple values"  displayed. Go to each line and do the right profile selection.

Optional: If you have another targets and extn associated with the app make sure to go in the capabilities group and select the ones that are enabled in the provisioning -profile. (You may check this from your developer portal) I face that my AppGroupID was selected wrongly once to profile I selected in the 1st tab of General.

Once the build settings are done correcting the General tab will show no issues. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem thanks to Vicky Dhas. The same problem occurred after creating a new certificate. On the tab «Build Settings» in the section "Signing" I fixed some settings:

[image: Correct settings]

Comment: Please write here the solution instead of including a link or image that could be broken in the future. Thanks!