# Xcode -Certificate status says "Not in Keychain" but the Certificates are visible inside Keychain Access

Tags: xcode, code-signing-certificate, p12

I got this computer in July. I had another computer before this and I [successfully exported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256893/4833705) the [signing certificate and it's private key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39846569/4833705) and added them to this computer. Everything has been working fine. I successfully pushed 2 apps to AppStoreConnect last week.

On Monday I had a weird error (different from this question) and Revoked a certificate by mistake. Ever since then I keep getting the error:

> Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your
>   keychain

[image]

When I go to `Xcode` > `Accounts` > `Apple IDs` > `Team` and click the `plus sign` it says

> Not in Keychain // 2nd pic

At first when I tried to pull the missing Distribution Certificate into `Keychain` > `login` I kept getting this:

[image]

When I try it on the command line I get `Segmentation fault: 11`:

```
$ security import /Users/Home/Desktop/Certificates_Folder/my@email/Certificate.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

$ Segmentation fault: 11
```

Oddly it let me send every other certificate to `login` except that distribution one.

So instead I created a new keychain item named `Brand_New_Keychain` and added both the certificates in there. When I check in `Brand_New_Keychain` both certificates are present and they are both in `System`.

I unchecked `Automatic`, deleted the developer team using the minus sign then added it back, I closed Xcode, restarted the computer, opened Xcode, etc same problem persists.

**As detailed in the photos below the Not in Keychain certificates are in Keychain Access. What is the problem here?**

1- Signing Error

[image]

2- Not in Keychain Message

[image]

3- Expiration Date from the `Development Certificate`

[image]

4- Expiration Date from the `Distribution Certificate`

[image]

5- The new Keychain item I created `Brand_New_Keychain` > `Certificates` > both certificates with the same expiration dates from pics 3 & 4 that it's saying I don't have in Keychain

[image]

6- When I pushed one of my apps up to AppStoreConnect it said I didn't have a `.p12` file for the app and created one for me. I downloaded it. This and it's `private key` is present in `Brand_New_Keychain` > `My Certificates` > the same expiration date as the missing `Distribution Certificate` from the 4th pic. The development certificate from the 3rd pic isn't here because I created it using the Revoke Certificate button from the 3rd pic. Afterwards I went to Apple and downloaded it but it never gave me a private key.

[image]

7- System > Certificates > both certificates with the same expiration dates from pics 3 & 4 that it's saying I don't have in Keychain

[image]

8- `developer.apple.com` > `Certificates` > both certificates with the same expiration dates from pics 3 & 4 that it's saying I don't have in Keychain. I downloaded both of these and the other 2, then clicked them all, dragged them into keychain, and even used `security import /Users/Home/Downloads/Certificate.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` to get each one in

[image]

9. I went back to the old computer and successfully exported the original `.p12` then imported in into Keychain so it's definitely there with it's private key.
10. Every certificate with a private key I changed the Access Control to `Allow all ...`:

[image]

**Update:**

@matt suggested I create a new **login** in Keychain Access which I did. **The same errors are still present** however the 2nd pic when I go to `Xcode` > `Accounts` > `Apple IDs` > `Team` and click the `plus sign` has **changed**. Now it says:

[image]

Comment: The answer to this question is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847332/4833705)