# Xcode -How to add a private key to Development Certificate if it's created using the Revoke button

Tags: xcode, code-signing, p12

By mistake I pressed the `Revoke` button.:

[image]

I went to `developer.apple` > `Certificates` I downloaded the new `Development Certificate` that was created from pressing the `Revoke` button. Afterwards one of the errors I got is

[image]

The second part of the error says the certificate needs a `private key` (in orange).

In `Xcode` > `Preferences` > `Accounts` > `App ID` > `Team` > `plus sign` it says the expiration of that `Development Certificate` is `10/30/20, 12:04 AM`:

[image]

When I look in keychain the certificate with that expiration date is there but there isn't an arrow on the left of it to toggle the nested private key:

[image]

**How do add a private key to the Development Certificate that was created using the Revoke button?**

Btw the Distribution Certificate that was created after pressing the `Revoke` button did have a private key attached to it.

Comment: "How do add a private key to the Development Certificate that was created using the Revoke button" What's the worry exactly? Unlike Distribution Certificates, you can have as many Development Certificates as you like. They don't get revoked. Just ask Xcode for a new one. (Of course if your keychain is hosed, as we've established elsewhere, that might not work.)

Comment: Oh ok, I thought the private key was necessary for the dev cer too. Thanks for the help man! Can you post it that as an answer so that the next person won’t break their brain trying to figure where it’s at?:)

Comment: The private key is necessary but when you ask Xcode to make you a development cert it does all the work, talking to the keychain to make the private key and downloading the cert into the keychain. But as I say, if your keychain is hosed, that might not work. Did you try it?

Comment: @matt in Xcode 11.2 it's necessary for the developer cer to have a private key. Even though Xcode generates it via the Revoke button for whatever reason the iPhone Developer cer private key is missing and causes 2 errors. I had to delete the iPhone Developer cert (created by the Revoke button) from the dev portal AND keychain. Then I had to manually create it myself and do all the necessary steps to add to the portal. Somebody in Apple made a mistake because in Xcode 11.2  the Revoke button iPhone Developer certificate doesn't create a key with it. Maybe Xcode 11.2.1 and above is different.

Comment: @matt btw when pressing the Revoke button the iPhone Distribution Certificate does get issued a private key and it works fine. Very odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you press the `Revoke` button you get issued a new `iPhone Distribution certificate` and a new `iPhone Developer certificate`. You can view these certificates inside the developer portal at `developer.apple` > `certificates`. Those certificates will also be inside your keychain. You use the certificate **expiration dates** to see which certificates correspond to what.

The problem with pressing the Revoke button is you will get a `iPhone Distribution certificate` with a `private key` but as far as the `iPhone Developer certificate` it **won't** have a private key.

If you look into your keychain you will see this pic below. Notice the `iPhone Distribution certificate` has a gray arrow next to it but the `iPhone Developer certificate` doesn't:

[image]

That will cause the following 2 errors:

[image]

It causes a cycle where you press the `Revoke` button again and you wind up with the same 2 errors. I'm not sure why Apple did it this way but someone definitely made a mistake.

When you go to `Keychain` > `login` > `My Certificates` you will only see certificates that have a private key (the gray arrow indicates that). Since the `iPhone Developer certificate` from pressing the Revoke button doesn't have a key it won't be in there.  [According to this](https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011331571-iOS-Common-Development-Issues-Keychain-Certificate-Profiles-) you need that key otherwise you'll get the errors:

> If your iOS developer and distribution certificates do not appear in
>   **"My Certificates"**, then they are not correctly configured for use on
>   your Mac. Please note that *"Certificates"* is a repository of all
>   certificates your Mac holds, whereas **"My Certificates"** is the subset
>   of certificates **valid for your Mac to actually use** - a certificate
>   appearing in *"Certificates"* only is not enough.
>
> **If the certificate is not in My Certificates** then this is most likely
>   because **you do not have the correct key for that certificate** also on
>   that Mac. You will need to locate the private key made for that
>   certificate (i.e., from the original Mac which requested the
>   certificate or a backup server).
>
> **As long as they do appear in My Certificates, then they key is there**.

Since the `iPhone Developer certificate` won't appear in **My Certificates** the fix is after you press the `Revoke` button, delete the `iPhone Developer certificate` that it generates from **BOTH** the developer portal at `developer.apple` > `certificates` **AND** `keychain`. **It's VERY important you delete it from keychain!** Use the **expiration date** to locate it. Please **keep** the `iPhone Distribution Certificate` because that should work fine and have a key (indicated by the gray arrow).

After it's deletes from both **BOTH** places you can manually generate a `developer certificate` yourself following [these directions](https://ioscodesigning.com/generating-code-signing-files/):

Generate a Code Signing Certificate manually

1- Open your `Keychain Access`.

2- In the upper left hand corner next to the Apple sign select `Keychain Access` > `Certificate Assistant` > `Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority..`.

3- Fill in **User Email Address**(just use yours) and the **Common Name** (just use your name) and select **Saved to Disk**. I selected `Let me specify key pair information` (maybe it's not necessary) but on the next screen just use the `Key Size: 2048 bits` and `algorithm: RSA`. Click on Continue and save the generated certSigningRequest file to your desktop.

4- Go to https://developer.apple.com and log in to your account.

5- Select Certificates, IDs & Profiles from the left sidebar.

6- Go to Certificates and click on the + button on the top right corner.

7- Select iOS App Development and click Continue.

8- On the next page you see the instructions for creating the certSigningRequest file. Click continue.

9- Upload the created certSigningRequest (from the 3rd step, the one saved to your desktop) to the form and click continue. It will generate your code signing certificate for you.

10- Download the certificate and double click to install it. Once installed it will be added to your Keychain Access app. Assuming it saves to your download folder you can just go in there and double click it.

Once you do those steps both errors should go away.

If you continue to have errors look at the certificates in both the portal at `developer.apple` > `certificates` and `keychain` > `My Certificates`. If anything is in the portal but isn't in `My Certificates` then you need to find it keychain access (look in keychain > *Certificates*), delete it, and delete it from the portal.

It took me a while to figure this out but the **expiration date** is the key to locating messed up certificates.

Comment: the problem with your answer is when you have developer account not-paid there is no way to go to developer.apple.com and do this because there is no option "Certificates, IDs & Profiles" on sidebar.

Comment: If you have a developer account this works fine. I never tried it without a developer account so I can’t speak on that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to make it working. I am on Mojave so:

1. I Installed Big Sur on external hard drive and booted it from there.
2. Installex Xcode 12.
3. Created empty project
4. I am member also in paid team but this is unnecessary.
5. Signing and creating certificate went smoothly without errors
6. I selected keychain access in system preferences in iCloud.
7. I exported my certificates and keys to external drive partition that is visible from Mojave.
8. restart and boot mojave
9. Imported certificates

and THIS IS NOT WORKING neither for paid account nor not-paid one. My certificates are marked as not trusted and Xcode 11.2 still has problems with repair and fix things. I got 8 emails that my certificates are revoked in the process.
So this probably is a Mojave think as Apple think system is not secure. Which is funny because yesterday I installed latest security update for Mojave (after which I lost my Mac Mini built-in speakers :( )
This looks like serious bug on Apple side I reported it through Feedback assistant but I doubt they will ever fix it so for now I have to say good bye to coding for Apple platforms.

Comment: Are you saying the answer doesn't work? It works fine for me. I ran into this issue more then once and this is what I used to get it working. 2 people up voted it so it must've worked for them too. Maybe you are missing a step. I'm using Catalina 10.15.7 but at the time I added the answer I believe I was on Mojave, but I can't be 100% sure about that.

Comment: I think I know what your problem might be. This actually happened to me before, my keychain got hosed. @matt in the comments was the one it brought it to my attention. It was in another question that I asked. Basically I had to recreate my keychain again. Look into that and see what happens. I would help you but I can't remember the steps that I took.

Comment: @LanceSamaria I am happy that it worked for you but obviously this is not widely working solution because for me and God-only-know how many others this didn't.
I googled "keychain hosed" however I am not sure if recreation of keychain helps, because my keychain works fine, all passwords are there and working. There must be an issue with something on Apple's side. Lives go on, I accepted to live with malfunctioned system.

Comment: Did you check if your keychain was hosed? That means you have to delete then reinstall your entire keychain. Google it

Comment: As I said my keychain is up and running :)

Comment: Sorry man, I wish I could help you. Did you contact Apple via AppStoreConnect? I called them before about an appId issue and they were really helpful. The rep tried to help me for about 45 minutes and couldn’t resolve the issue. He said he never encountered it before. He took my email and then sent it up the chain to the super pros and they figured out the issue. They contacted me a day or two later.

Comment: @LanceSamaria No, If I remember AppStoreConnect is only for paid developers. I'm happy for you they were able to help, but knowing my luck they would sent it two levels in chain of command and still not resolve. I often encounter problems nobody ever found solution for :)

Comment: Lol, dang sorry to hear that. I’m a little lost about something though. In your answer you said “this is not working neither for paid account ...” but it sounds like you are saying you can’t contact AppStoreConnect because it is for paid developers.