# Moving Xcode Archives to another computer

Tags: xcode

I'm facing this issue: I want to Archive my app in my computer but to upload it to the AppStore from another computer. It's possible to transfer only the archive from the "Organizer"?

I need to transfer something else? 
How I can manually add another app to the "Organizer"?

Comment: Why don't you just create the .ipa file and transfer and then upload using `transporter` app.

Comment: @onCompletion Does it transfer the provision and the certificates also?

Comment: No, certificates it won't transfer but I don't think it requires certificates further to upload it once you have created the .ipa file. Generally transporter will ask to login to the account and do the job for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. Your archives are in *~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives* and are transferable from that spot in one machine to that spot on another machine. So you can then use Xcode on the other machine to do exactly what you would have done on the first machine. I have performed this kind of migration many times!

You will, of course, have to configure your credentials in the keychain of the second machine, but they too are transferable by export/import. (See [Distribution certificate / private key not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256780/distribution-certificate-private-key-not-installed) for more about.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I always assumed there were metadata files somewhere and never tried, but indeed copying the .xcarchive file, even with the Organizer open on the destination machine, just works! I'll check back in a few hours to award the bounty (I can't yet), thank you again!