# Apple distribution certificate missing private key

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, keychain

I know this has been asked multiple times and I have went through several stackoverflow answers and Apple dev forums and followed all the given advice but this is not working for me. I keep getting this error.

[image]

I have revoked certificates, created new ones, deleted everything in my keychain associated with the account. Generated new private keys and distribution certificates. Nothing I tried has worked. I even contacted Apple directly and their instructions did not work as well. What am I doing wrong? I have been attempting to solve this for over a month now.

These are the things I have done so far:

- [Revoke Existing Distribution Certificate](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev7d381a7ff)
- [Delete Signing Certificate](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09?sub=devde8d0e98a)
- [Followed the answers given in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256780/distribution-certificate-private-key-not-installed)

Comment: A more specific description of what you've done would help. Not everything, obviously, but a list of the specific steps that you're using that you think should work, but which fail for you.

Comment: Hi @Caleb I have updated my answer

Comment: I'm having the same problem and have been through the same resolutions as @spongyboss to no effect. But spongyboss - what version of mac OS and xcode are you using?

Comment: @luke_f I am using Mojave (10.14.6) and Xcode 11.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Export the certificate from the keychain (keeping the folder open showing the private key) of the device on which the certificate was download the exported .p12 and verify if the private key is showing on the keychain if not the recently added certificate from key chain , Go to  > My Certificates and drag and drop the .p12

This resolved my issue.