# Apple Distribution Certificate Creator Mismatch

Tags: xcode, certificate

I am on a Mac (10.14.6) with Xcode 11.3.1 and have an App, I last updated 2019, where everything for deployment went just fine (especially signing). Recently I added new functionality and build the Archive in Xcode alright. Now I try to "Validate App", with "Automatically manage signing".
Xcode generates the "Apple Distribution Certificate" ok, but in the next step it says, that the private key is not found for the Certificate. Looking in Keychain, the private key and certificate are there. In Xcode "manage certficates" shows two lines:
[Manage Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRM04.png).

The second line is the Certificate recognized by Xcode, but appearently Xcode wants the first line. The only difference is the Creator Name. To my knowledge I have no influence on the creator name, should be the full name of the Apple developer account.

I already revoked the Certificates in the developer account @apple and deleted the key/cert in the Keychain and redid the process (as [suggested elsewhere here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256780/distribution-certificate-private-key-not-installed)), also closing/reopening XCode with no success. Also created an "iOS Distribution Certificate" in the apple developer account, but appearantly Apple nowadays wants an "Apple Distribution Certificate".

So what can I do if Xcode does not recognize the self generated key/cert?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to resolve the issue (after trying on another Mac for it to work). Update OSX to BigSur and Xcode to 12.4. BigSur alone didn't do the trick (but rendered a couple of my programs useless, thank you Apple).
Updating Xcode over the normal (german) AppStore did not work. I had to use [this link](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) to find the update to Xcode.

Now the "Validate App" works just fine, so I suppose it's just a bug in Xcode 11.3.1.