# missing private key in jos distribution want to

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to upload project to testflight, I can't upload the app have this problem [image]

this is keychain:
[image]

I've exported the two selected items and open the exported certificate again with key chain, and I've downloaded the certificate in apple developer account and open it in key chain, but it still have the same problem, I've seen many answers and I tried them but no one solved my problem, so what is the solution with my problem?

Comment: Are you developing on two machines?

Comment: @matt yes......

Comment: OK, instead of using the keychain, try this: on the working machine, go to Xcode Preferences > Accounts > Manage Certificates and export the needed certificates from there. (Control-click on a certificate and choose Export from the contextual menu.) Open that on the other machine.

Comment: @matt I can't export export certificate I got this error the operation could not be completed No other information is available about the problem.

Comment: Okay, well, then I suggest you just start from the ground up. Instead of trying to pretend to be a different user, use your own member identity to create a distribution certificate. You might have to revoke the existing certificate, as there can be only one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867878/missing-private-key-in-the-distribution-certificate-on-keychain