# Cannot upload ios app due to User has one ios distribution certificate but its private key is not installed." Error Message

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing iphone App on Xcode (Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)) with Mid 2012 Mac book Pro. I am unable to upload the app because Xcode is issuing the following error message:

> User has one ios distribution certificate but its private key is not installed. contact the creator of this certificate to get a copy of the private key

I have saved the private key Untitled.p12 on my machine and double clicked. But it is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [missing private key in the distribution certificate on keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867878/missing-private-key-in-the-distribution-certificate-on-keychain)

Comment: @udbhateja: That does not answer my question because i exported .p12 file on my same computer and double clicked that file too. So no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode Version 10.2.1  is not allowed to upload ios app on app store. It is impossible. Thanks